# “...than there are” vs “than”

Tags: grammar, comparative

I'd like to know which one of these sentences are grammatically correct. Is there any difference in meaning between them?

1. There are more cars **than there are** people in this country.
2. There are more cars **than** people in this country.
3. There are more cars in this country **than there are** people
4. There are more cars in this country **than** people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all appear grammatically correct to me. Really the only difference is that some of the sentences are using more words than is necessary to convey the same meaning. For example, sentences 1 and 3 could go without "there are".

I suppose one could argue that sentences 3 and 4 make it more immediately apparent what place you are referring to (i.e. "this country") which might have a positive effect on clarification.

Another thing to consider is that if this were somebody speaking - at least from my experience - they'd be more prone to say sentences 2 and 4 because there is a tendency to be less formal.